# Alterar altura de elemento no ScrollView horizontal

Tags: javascript, react, mobile, react-native

Como faço para que um ScrollView horizontal redimensione a altura baseada no card ativo?

O problema ocorre quando uma lista tem 600px de altura (por exemplo) e outra lista tem 300px. O esperado é que a altura do ScrollView redimensione. Caso não fique claro, uma imagem de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei utilizar Animated, FlatList, Gesture Handler e nada resolveu.

Gif mostrando o problema:

[image: Gif mostrando o problema]

Como fazer esse efeito?